# SQL - return the smallest value in one column that matches the value of another column

Tags: sql

How can I return in column4 the smallest number from column3 based on column1?

```
1   100 1
2   100 1
1   101 2
1   102 4
2   200 19
3   200 19
16  200 19
18  200 19
19  200 19
20  200 19
3   301 28
6   301 28
3   302 29
3   310 30
4   400 31
4   410 32
4   420 33
5   500 34
7   500 34
5   510 35
6   510 35
5   520 36
6   610 37
7   700 38
7   701 39
8   701 39
8   800 40
8   802 41
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "based on column 1"?  You mean the smallest value of column 3 that has the same value as column 1?

Comment: @ D Stanley - for every value in column1 search to corresponding values in column3 and return the smallest one

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @ Adam Porad - I am lacking the SQL logic that is why I am asking the question here, I have build this in excel already using MIN(IF) array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join to a subquery that calculates the minimums for each col1:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, mcol3
from mytable a
join (select col1, min(col3) mcol3 from mytable group by col1) b
  on b.col1 = a.col1
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/956ce/2), showing this output from your sample data:

```
1   100 1   1
2   100 1   1
1   101 2   1
1   102 4   1
2   200 19  1
3   200 19  19
16  200 19  19
18  200 19  19
19  200 19  19
20  200 19  19
3   301 28  19
6   301 28  28
3   302 29  19
3   310 30  19
4   400 31  31
4   410 32  31
4   420 33  31
5   500 34  34
7   500 34  34
5   510 35  34
6   510 35  28
5   520 36  34
6   610 37  28
7   700 38  34
7   701 39  34
8   701 39  39
8   800 40  39
8   802 41  39
```

Comment: Thank you it`s doing exactly want I was hoping it will do!